# Runtime error 6 - Overflow, variable set as Long

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, autofilter

I am having problem executing the copy+paste for a filtered data. My code does not encounter error if filtered field will have a 0 result or > 1. However, if there's 1 record visible after filter, Runtime error 6 appears. Please see code used below:

```
Dim wsDue As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim y As Long
Dim x As Long

x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Yes"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Set wsDue = Worksheets("Due")
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Target List Consolidated")
y = wsDue.Range("B" & wsDue.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If wsDue.Range(wsDue.Cells(2, 2), wsDue.Cells(y, 2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
    wsDue.Range("B2:B" & x).Copy
    wsTarget.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
Else:
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `wsDue.Range("B2:B" & y).Copy` ?

Comment: Aren't **x** and **y** the same thing now? Are they supposed to be from different worksheets? Why define one parent worksheet and not the other?

Comment: it worked!! I removed y and just used x. Thanks @Jeeped

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure your Excel (aka MS-Office) has all applicable service packs. The problem with a single filtered row being interpreted as all rows was a known bug but it was rectified in subsequent service packs.

You can also apply some 'best practices' code to avoid it happening altogether. The [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) can be used to localize the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx). Use progressive [With ... End With statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to further isolate the data to be transfered.

```
Dim wsDue As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet

With Worksheets("Due")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    'work on the contiguous block of cells radiating out from A1
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        'apply the AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Yes"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        'shift one row down (off the header row) and resize one less row
        'isolate column B
        With .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
            'non-destructive test to see if there are any rows visible
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Target List Consolidated")
                .Copy
                wsTarget.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial _
                    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
            End If
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Comment: I tried to revise the code:
`Dim wsDue As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet, x As Long
x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Yes"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Set wsDue = Worksheets("Due")
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Target List Consolidated")

If wsDue.Range("B1:B" & x).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
    wsDue.Range("B1:B" & x).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsTarget.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
Else:
End If`

Comment: do you think I will still encounter any error with the revised code to copy filtered result?

Comment: Two things remain unclear. a) I still don't know where you are getting hte **x** from; it seems like it should be **y**. b) I do not understand why you are filtering column B from **Yes** and then copying column B to another worksheet's column A. The code above is tested and works as per your original question. Please not post revised code into a comment; revise your original question or ask another.

Comment: a. I have edited the question and add the variable x
b. I need to filter those which are tagged as Yes (Col B of the original worksheet) to Col A of another worksheet. I just removed the code to copy results of the other column to an assigned column in another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way to work around as a solution. I used the following code instead:

```
Dim x As Long
Dim wsDue As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

x = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Yes"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Set wsDue = Worksheets("Due")
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Target List Consolidated")

If wsDue.Range("B1:B" & x).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
    wsDue.Range("B1:B" & x).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsTarget.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Else:
End If
```

The solution was able to get the result of filter and will copy the desired range excluding the header in Row 1.